# How to update swiper.js if state changes in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I have a state “isOpen=false” and I need to update or reinitialize swiper.js when state changes to true. How is it possible to do?

```
@observable 
public isOpen=false

private DOMTopSwiper = createRef<HTMLDivElement>()

const topSwiper = new Swiper(this.DOMTopSwiper.current, {
  spaceBetween: 0,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".top-swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".top-swiper-button-prev",
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use this https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper and then inject a props to the Swiper component that is a reference to the parent component State.

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';

class Example extends React.Component {

  state={
     isOpen:false
  };

  render() {
    const params = {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
      },
      spaceBetween: 30
    }

    return(
      <Swiper isOpen={this.state.isOpen} {...params}>
        <div>Slide 1</div>
        <div>Slide 2</div>
        <div>Slide 3</div>
        <div>Slide 4</div>
        <div>Slide 5</div>
      </Swiper>
    )
  }
}

export default Example;
```